# Azure VNet IP address charges

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I have created a Virtual network with following CIDR. This address space has 256 total address.

```
CIDR 10.0.0.0/24
```

will i be billed for all available/reserved IP addresses? If we check [Azure IP Address Price](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/ip-addresses/) it says we need to pay for both reserved and used IP addresses. In this case if someone creates a vnet of say /16 or /8 his bill should sky rocket.

Azure has also create default subnet with CIDR /8 when i create kubernetes cluster without mentioning virtaul network with it. If they charge for reserved address space then this should have huge cost associated with.

Please confirm how azure charge for IP address range created using CIDR.

Answer (score 0):

Azure only charges you for reserved *PUBLIC* IP addresses. Your VNET uses a private address space, so no costs for that will occur.